# Custom federated web service authenticators

Tags: git, maven, wso2-identity-server

I need to authenticate users against a corporate web service in WSO2 Identity Server. I have found this blog:

http://techreadme.blogspot.com.es/2015/08/wso2-identity-server-use-case.html

and download the code from git. I need to implement a custom federated authenticator. 
The sample code doesn`t work, maven does not look for the correct urls and the POM.xml does not seem to be correct. 
¿Did someone get the code working?. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a custom federated authenticator

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Writing+a+Custom+Federated+Authenticator

Comment: Hi Giordano. This is precisely why I am  trying to make the blog example work.

Answer (score 0):

The sample may not be working due to missing wso2 nexus repository references. Try adding that section from [here](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity-framework/blob/v5.8.0/pom.xml#L77-L114) to the sample's root pom.

On a related note, the above sample seems to have written for IS 5.0.0. So ,some of the dependencies may need to be updated if you are writing this for latest IS version (5.3.0)